# How to solve these errors: slot of x need be populated with unique names, or subscript contains out-of-bounds indices, using predORF?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, genome

I am having some problems with this function predORF

```
  sqa <- c("CAGGGCACCTGGCCTTGGGATGCGCCTCCTGCCCGCTGAGCCCAGGGGCCGCTATGGCCCTTCTGGCCATGCTGGCGCTGCAGACAGCTCTCTACCTAGTAGGCTTCTTCTACCCGCCGGGAGGCATATGGCGCTGGATCACCCGGGAC") 
  print(sqa)
```

First, I transformed the sequence into the input formats

```
  dnastring = DNAString(sqa) 
  print(dnastring)

  dna <- DNAStringSet(sqa) 
  print(dna)
```

When I use DNAstrings format:

```
    predORF(dnabase, n = 1, type = "grl", 
    mode = "orf", strand = "sense", 
    longest_disjoint=FALSE, 
    startcodon = c("ATG"), 
    stopcodon = c("TAA"))
```

I got this error

```
  Error in predORF(dnastring, n = 1, type = "grl", mode = "orf", strand = "sense",  : 
  Sequence name slot of x need be populated with unique names.
```

When I define its length, i got this:

```
    predORF(dna[:149], n = 1, type = "grl", 
    mode = "orf", strand = "sense", 
    longest_disjoint=FALSE, 
    startcodon = c("ATG"), 
    stopcodon = c("TAA"))

  Error in predORF(dnastring[1:149], n = 1, type = "grl", mode = "orf",  : 
  Sequence name slot of x need be populated with unique names.
```

When I use DNAStringSet format:

```
    predORF(dna, n = 1, type = "grl", 
    mode = "orf", strand = "sense", 
    longest_disjoint=FALSE, 
    startcodon = c("ATG"), 
    stopcodon = c("TAA"))
```

I got this error

```
  Error in predORF(dna n = 1, type = "grl", mode = "orf", strand = "sense",  : 
  Sequence name slot of x need be populated with unique names.
```

When I define its length, i got this:

```
    predORF(dna[:149], n = 1, type = "grl", 
    mode = "orf", strand = "sense", 
    longest_disjoint=FALSE, 
    startcodon = c("ATG"), 
    stopcodon = c("TAA"))

  Error: subscript contains out-of-bounds indices
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that predORF needs named sequences as input. See below:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(systemPipeR)

sqa <- c("ATGTAA")
sqb <- c("ATGGCCTAA")
dna <- DNAStringSet(c(seq_a = sqa, seq_b = sqb), use.names = T) 
predORF(dna, n = 1, type = "grl", 
        mode = "orf", strand = "sense", 
        longest_disjoint=FALSE, 
        startcodon = c("ATG"), 
        stopcodon = c("TAA"))
```